# Testing "homogeneity", strong correlation and low p-value

Tags: r, correlation, t-test

I have the following data :

```
 a=c(107,135,122,67,65,53,19,32)
 b=c(35.5,26,9,4.5,5.33,9.83,0,1)
```

I predict a "resemblance" in the result of these groups and no big change.
so my :
H0 would be that the two means of the groups are not really very different
H1 : the two means of the groups are different.

I tried a

```
cor.test(a,b)
Pearson's product-moment correlation

data:  a and b
t = 2.6938, df = 6, p-value = 0.03587
alternative hypothesis: true correlation is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.07352902 0.94950291
sample estimates:
      cor 
0.7398666 

Edit1: t.test(a,b)
Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  a and b
t = 4.0828, df = 8.253, p-value = 0.003296
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 27.87149 99.33851
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
   75.000    11.395
```

My questions are :

- With this method I would never be able to prove that the two distributions are not very differents because if p<0.05 I will reject H0, in consequence, I will reject that the two samples are not differents. And if p>0.05 I will fail to reject H0 but it do not mean that my samples are not different. How should I work when in fact I want to prove that there is no change between my two groups ?
- In this case I have strong correlation which is great. Correlation mesure the intensity of relation between my variables. However I have p<0.05 which mean that I should reject H0 and that my two groups are in fact very different.

What wrong with my analyses ?

Comment: Did you ran a `cor.test`, or a `t.test`? The output doesn't match the command.

Comment: In fact, please look to my EDIT1 for the t.test. Thanks.

Comment: While proving no effect under standard null-hypothesis testing is impossible, a simple way would be to run the test, find $p>0.05$, and run power calculations to show that if the effect were at least $x$ you'd have detected it with 90% probability. However, I'm not sure why you expect the group means to be not different when the values are so clearly different - around 50-100 for one sample and 1-10 for the other.

Comment: Apologize, I do not understand what you mean by "running a power calculations", do you have code example about that please ? In addition, does the coefficient of correlation indicate the relation between variables. In other words how it is possible to have strong correlation and low p-value ?

Comment: It is too broad to explain here, but I would suggest searching for "power calculation tutorial", for example, this one comes with R code: http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/power.html And something on correlation tests: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat501/node/259 - you will see that low p-value indicates that correlation is not equal to 0, and says nothing about group means.

Comment: please note that the word "data" is already plural (so you should not add an "s"). Something to keep in mind on your next edit.